# Retrieve Column having words matching with any of those words mentioned below

Tags: sql-server

WE need to find whether Table having column1, column2,column3,column4 contains 
any of the matching words existing on word if its there it should show me the result from a table

word=`'adsa sad Co., Ltd. CZ 565 AA  Rd Block B Wang, SDSD 5756756 HP 5656 Vinayak Rd Block B 201203 asdsds China, AAA Republic'`

```
Select *  from ABCTable 
where Column1 like '%adsa sad Co., Ltd. CZ 565 AA  Rd Block B Wang, SDSD 5756756 HP 5656 Vinayak Rd Block B 201203 asdsds China, AAA Republic%'
```

It is not working though this columns is having  5756756  stored.

Below is my Code.

```
 Declare @mytable table (column1 nvarchar(max),column2 nvarchar(max),column3 nvarchar(max))
insert into @mytable values ('201203','','')
insert into @mytable values ('52013','','')
insert into @mytable values ('52012454543','','')

declare @input nvarchar(max) = 'adsa sad Co., Ltd. CZ 565 AA Rd Block B Wang, SDSD 5756756 HP 5656 Vinayak Rd Block B 201203 asdsds China, AAA Republic'

select *
from @mytable
where @input like N'%'+column1+N'%'
    or @input like N'%'+column2+N'%'
    or @input like N'%'+column3+N'%'
```

Comment: `'%adsa sad Co., Ltd. CZ 565 AA Rd Block B Wang, SDSD 5756756 HP 5656 Vinayak Rd Block B 201203 asdsds China, AAA Republic%` will search for this whole string with prefix and postfix string. Do you want to find this whole string or any of the individual words from this string ?

Comment: Why you want to search for the entire string? You should search for the particular word instead.

Comment: Because any of the string word can be available on any of those columns if its matches i need to retrieve Rows

Answer (score 0):

Like works the other way around. If you are looking '201203' in the long string. Than you put the long string before like and the number with %'s after the like.

```
Declare @mytable table (column1 nvarchar(max),column2 nvarchar(max),column3 nvarchar(max))
insert into @mytable values 
('201203',NULL,NULL)
,('52013',Null,NULL)
,('52012454543',NULL,NULL)

declare @input nvarchar(max) = 'adsa sad Co., Ltd. CZ 565 AA Rd Block B Wang, SDSD 5756756 HP 5656 Vinayak Rd Block B 201203 asdsds China, AAA Republic'

select *
from @mytable
where @input like N'%'+column1+N'%'
    or @input like N'%'+column2+N'%'
    or @input like N'%'+column3+N'%'
```

Comment: How did it not work? The query returns the row, right. Please elaborate.

Comment: WHEN I SELECT I NEED SPECIFIC RECORD LIKE  Row containing 5756756  Only  SHOULD BE THE ONLY WORD PRESENT BUT CURRENTLY IF I Use your Query on Multiple Rows it will display all the rows  you can test your query afer inserting 3 rows and than  use select query it will display all three rows

Comment: @Peter- I have updated  my question and if you run the query you will get  3 rows i Need only single row having same  record present on table.

Comment: @ashish9780 The solution did not work because of the emty strings. I've updated my answer.